# "Unauthorized" when GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/presence

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/presence (/communications/getPresencesByUserId, /users/{id}/presence)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b13dbf1b-16b2-4c41-90ee-103b46d9890f",
      "date": "2020-05-27T09:18:43"
    }
  }
}
```

Checked in jwt, token has scopes:
**"scp": "... Presence.Read Presence.Read.All ..."**

Logged in with the same user in Graph Explorer. The response was Forbidden but after giving consent it works fine in Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph Explorer will not interact with your application,So you need to provide permissions for Graph Explorer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use @microsoft/teams-js for authorization. I updated version from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 and now I have no issues with getting presence.